# TypeError: this.state.merchentOrders.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    I am new to react when I trying to fetch JSON data on a table using map function an error is thrown.
    TypeError: this.state.merchentOrders.map is not a function
```

why is telling this .state.merchentOrders.map is not a function and when loading the JSON data but I can take it to other tags problem occur when I am trying to loop the data to table use map function as below.
  I am new to react when I trying to fetch JSON data on a table using map function an error is thrown.
    TypeError: this.state.merchentOrders.map is not a function  I am new to react when I trying to fetch JSON data on a table using map function an error is thrown.
    TypeError: this.state.merchentOrders.map is not a function

```
    class Order extends Component{

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          loading:true,
          merchentOrders: []
        }

      }

 //calling the URL 
      async componentDidMount() {
          const url="https://api.randomuser.me/";
          const response=await fetch(url);
          const data=await response.json();
          this.setState({merchentOrders:data.results[0],loading:false})
          console.log(data.results[0]);

      }
      render() {
        return 
                    <Table hover bordered striped responsive size="sm">
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Date registered</th>

                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
//when i trying to use the map function here the error thrown

                      { !this.state.loading ? **this.state.merchentOrders.map**(row => (
                        <tr key={row.name.first}>

                          <td>{row.name.last}</td>
                          <td>{row.name.last}</td>

                        </tr>
                      )) :  (<div>loading....</div>)
                      }

                      </tbody>
                    </Table>

          </div>

        )
      }
    }

    export default Order;
```

Comment: Do note that the proper spelling is `merchant`, you may wish to fix that to avoid confusing future readers of the code. Does your `console.log(data.results[0]);` log an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're setting the first entry from results into `merchentOrders`, you don't have an iterable array to map over:

You should be doing

```
this.setState({merchentOrders:data.results,loading:false})
```

And then, u can map over like so

```
{
  !this.state.loading ? (
    this.state.merchentOrders.map(row => (
      <tr key={row.name.first}>
        <td>{row.name.last}</td>
        <td>{row.name.last}</td>
      </tr>
    ))
  ) : (
    <div>Loading</div>
  );
}
```